# DocuSign API -Template possibilities

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to make a DocuSign API call to use Template that has already created in the portal and auto fill few fields like recipient Name,email etc. and send to the given recipient.

Actually the idea is like create the needed template in docusign portal and then the API going to work to email to the recipient.

I appreciate your response.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.
Look at this code example showing how to do this - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/